# Xamarin.Forms Maps crashing app

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a hard time trying to show a map on my Xamarin Forms app. This is the error I get everytime I open the page with the map:

```
0x29 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal    C#
0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException  C#
0x6 in Android.Runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler.UncaughtException at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/UncaughtExceptionHandler.cs:35,4 C#
0x1C in Java.Lang.Thread.IUncaughtExceptionHandlerInvoker.n_UncaughtException_Ljava_lang_Thread_Ljava_lang_Throwable_ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Java.Lang.Thread.cs:221,5 C#
0x1D in object.28d67210-c8ee-4f17-9d83-36104107982d C#
```

This is the code for creating the page:

```
var topLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37,-122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        }
    }
};

var bottomLayout = new StackLayout { Children = { ... }  }; //shortened for readability

Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children = { topLayout, bottomLayout }
};
```

I'm saying the problem is the map, because if I change the "new Map" line for a Label, for instance, it works.

I'm instantiating the Maps FW as said here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new FullHelp.App());
}
```

Comment: You didnt post exception name. Please add it.
BTW, in latest xamarin they broke exception stacktraces. Try to install old one (8.9 should be OK) and to look at the exact exception.

Comment: Did you also add the Maps key in the configuration and checked the required permissions?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis no, but according to the provided documentation that shouldn't be an issue. At the link they say if you don't provide the map keys xamarin would display a gray box. About the permissions I let that one slip, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @Grigory that's all the info I was presented. Unhandled exception =/

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?  If you can zip the solution up I will take a look for you?  My contact details are on my profile page.

Comment: @Pete Alright, thank you. I'll do that. I'm using v1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your solution for `Android`, and yes it did throw an `Exception`.

In the `Debug --> Exceptions` dialog box, if you click the `Thrown` checkbox for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` you will get a more meaningful description of the exception to be resolved.

[image]

The exception detail thrown is:

```
'Java.Lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:valu…'
```

Looking at your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have no keys defined / capabilities.

Refer to [this link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/) that will discuss how to configure your `Xamarin.Forms` application to handle `Maps` integration as you appear to be missing some things.

There is more detail on my other StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381016/xamarin-google-map-not-working/26384238#26384238) that details how to create the API key for Andorid.

Comment: Thank you, although I don't understand why the Xamarin tutorial said they were not needed in order to test. Thank you for the help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Hold short keys **`Ctrl+Alt+E`** to open Exceptions in Visual Studio.